# How to convert units in XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert XML like this

```
<product>
    <package>3.9L</package>
</product>
<product>
    <package>250g</package>
</product>
<product>
    <package>2.8kg</package>
</product>
```

to XML like this

```
<product>
    <weight>3.9</weight>
    <unit>L</unit>
</product>
<product>
    <weight>0.25</weight>
    <unit>g</unit>
</product>
<product>
    <weight>2.8</weight>
    <unit>kg</unit>
</product>
```

I need to separate the numeric and text part of package and according to text part (unit) decide what formula will be used to calculate weight.
Any ideas how to do that using XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `translate` as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="package">
    <weight>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., '0123456789.', ''), '')"/>
    </weight>
    <unit>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '0123456789.', '')"/>
    </unit>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to, but it is a good idea and now I know how to do that. Thanks.